# How to use returning with Vapor's PostgreSQL driver

Tags: swift, postgresql, vapor, sql-returning

I'm using Vapor for an API, with the PostgreSQL driver (no fluent). In my controller, I want to return the inserted/updated item, I found there is a `returning` function in the driver which takes an object of type `PostgreSQLSelectExpression`.  Vapor's documentation is terrible, and I've found no examples on how to use this function.

So I'd like to know what should I pass to the function if I wanted to get all columns, one column, and multiple (but not all) columns, and also if it is possible to give aliases to the columns.

To be clear: I understand how the `returning` clause works using raw SQL, but I really prefer to use the query builder if there is a built in way to do this.

**Update**

To be more specific about what I'm asking here: I want to know is how do I get a `PostgreSQLSelectExpression` since the documents for it are really confusing. I tried using `KeyPath`s but it doesn't work.

So the question is: how do I get a `PostgreSQLSelectExpression` that gets me back (a) all the columns (b) a single column and (c) multiple but not all columns.

Given:

```swift
//MyModel.swift
struct MyModel: SQLTable {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}

//MyModelController.swift
connection.insert(into: MyModel.self)
.value(myModel)
.returning(/*what should I use here to get a, b, and c?*/)
```

Comment: You could try to use SwifQL, with it it is pretty clear